# remove lines from file 1 that match elements in specific column from file 2

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have a file A.txt like this (the real one has ~1000 rows and ~70,000 columns):

```
ID    SEX    A    B    C
45    1    4.5    9.2    5.4
34    0    3.4    4.5    9.0
2    0    3.5    7.8    0.7
56    1    5.6    7.6    0.7
```

and a file B.txt like this (the real one has ~600 rows):

```
45
2
```

I want to remove all rows from A.txt whose ID matches the IDs from file B.txt. Expected output (file C.txt):

```
ID    SEX    A    B    C
34    0    3.4    4.5    9.0
56    1    5.6    7.6    0.7
```

I was thinking in something like:
grep -v -f B.txt A.txt > C.txt

but this script does not specify the column of A.txt

Comment: convert the "list" file to records like `'/^2$/d'` (one per line) and feed to `sed` like `sed -f "listFile" mainFile > outputFile`. You can fix the "listFile" with something like `sed 's:.*:/^&$/:' baseList > listFile`. Only work on copies! Sorry about the `join` advice (now removed), I missed the 70,000 column thing. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the lines of B.txt into regular expressions anchored to the beginning of the line:

```sh
$ grep -v -f <(sed 's/.*/^&[[:space:]]/' B.txt) A.txt
ID    SEX    A    B    C
34    0    3.4    4.5    9.0
56    1    5.6    7.6    0.7
```

(This assumes you're using `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`, or another shell that supports `<()` command redirection.)